# Помогите обойти защиту от парсинга

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Нужно вытащить html код с сайта marketwatch.com
Делаю это таким способом:

```
#первый две строки не важны, в них я вытаскиваю рандомный юзерагент и использую его в запросе
useragents = open('/home/ubuntu/bot/useragents.txt').read().split('\n')
useragent = {'User-Agent': choice(useragents)}
response = requests.get(url, verify=True, headers=useragent)
return response.text
```

Раньше это все работало, но сейчас видимо поставили какую-то защиту и все что мне возвращает это:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/distil_r_captcha.html?requestId=3130ab7e-7dc1-4353-bfe0-15e09c163fc9&httpReferrer=%2Finvesting%2Ffuture%2Fdjia%2520futures" />
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(window){
    try {
        if (typeof sessionStorage !== 'undefined'){
            sessionStorage.setItem('distil_referrer', document.referrer);
        }
    } catch (e){}
})(window);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lxwtsparqmgdowhx.js" defer></script>    <style type="text/css">#d__fFH{position:absolute;top:-5000px;left:-5000px}#d__fF{font-family:serif;font-size:200px;visibility:hidden}#fwqssyztxufxfzwwduebdqwxedwrzazqaaavux{display:none!important}</style></head>
<body>
<div id="distilIdentificationBlock">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как обойти защиту и достучатся до содержимого?

Comment: меня терзают смутные сомненья, у вас там не капча ли случаем?

Comment: Нет, капчи там нету

Comment: Вы уверены? вот что видно по вашему запросу: https://www.marketwatch.com/distil_r_captcha.html?requestId=3130ab7e-7dc1-4353-bfe0-15e09c163fc9&httpReferrer=%2Finvesting%2Ffuture%2Fdjia%2520futures

Comment: Хм.. Значит да, сайт как-то выкупает что это бот и перенаправляет его на капчу. Есть какие-то варианты?

Comment: IP попал в "черный список"

Comment: Maxon Вы походу их заколебали со своим роботом вот они поставили капчу)

Comment: Зачем кстати ( рандомный юзер) агент?

Comment: Вообще зайдите с браузера на сайт пройдите капчу посмотрите заголовки которые отправляет браузер и такие - же отправьте. у вас походу статичный IP  адрес а вы юзер агент отправляете как будто у вас на компе сто браузеров стоит )))))))))